# TypeScript React - useReducer with Array of Objects in Interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks, use-reducer

I've created the following component:

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react'

type ACTION_TYPE = | {type: 'SET_USER', userId: number} | {type: 'DELETE_USER', userId: number, deleteMessages: boolean}

interface User { 
    id : number; 
    name? : string; 
    surname?: string; 
    hasDiscount?: boolean;
}


const myReducer = (state : typeof initialState, action : ACTION_TYPE) => { 
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'DELETE_USER':
            return {users: [...state.users, {id: action.userId}]}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const initialState = {
    users : []
}

const TestingComponent : React.FC = () => { 

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(myReducer,initialState)


    return (
<div></div>
    )
}

export default TestingComponent
```

I'm getting an error on my `useReducer` - `No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction<any>, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error. Argument of type '(state: typeof initialState, action: ACTION_TYPE) => { users: { id: number; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'. Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: { users: never[]; }, action: ACTION_TYPE) => { users: { id: number; }[]; }, initialState: never, initializer?: undefined): [never, Dispatch<ACTION_TYPE>]', gave the following error. Argument of type '{ users: never[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2769)`

I'm not sure how to interpret this though - I've also tried creating the following interface

```
interface USER_STATE { 
    users: [User]
}
```

and using it in `myReducer` to define the type of `state` - but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"typescript": "^4.3.5"`. You need to use type assertion to specify `User[]` type for `state.users`:

```
const initialState = {
  users: [] as User[],
};
```

So that `typeof initialState` will infer a correct state type. Otherwise, TS will infer `typeof initialState` to `{ users: never[]; }` type.